# How do i copy the all worksheets using xlwings module in python?

Tags: python, xlwings

I have a macro excel file, it's having 3 worksheets. I need to saveas or copy all worksheets to new excel sheet. How to do in python using xlwing module?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62970113/13526701 this?

Comment: For macro file I  am getting error,

Comment: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Workbook is protected and cannot be changed.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: Code please? Just edit your question, its going to be more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I cannot comment yet, so I will have to "answer". For pwintypes errors it is many times caused by Trust Center setting issues. Please see this link https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html . Also, like NoBlockhit asked, some code would help.

Comment: Thank you for valuable time taken for answer to this question.